# How to manage exceptions in ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In list whitch I'am downloading there is a parameter:

`taf[index]['change']['indicator']['text']`

in:

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: taf.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('Indicator: ' +
                      taf[index]['change']['indicator']['text']), // !!This element sometimes is present sometimes not!!
                  Text('Valid from: ' + taf[index]['timestamp']['from']),
                  Text('Valid to: ' + taf[index]['timestamp']['to'])
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

whitch sometimes in present in downloaded data sometimes no. My question is how to handle this to do not crash the app diring the ListView.builder function when varaying paramater is not present?

**EDIT: If you know alternative for building a list view but with irregular elements let me know :)**

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7gw0.png)

[ListView.builder with problematic parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MZIW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ListView.builder(
          itemCount: taf.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {


            var changeIndicatorText = taf[index]['change']!=null?
taf[index]['change']['indicator']!= null?
    (taf[index]['change']['indicator']['text']??""):"";
            return Card(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('Indicator: ' + changeIndicatorText), 
    // !!This element sometimes is present sometimes not!!
              Text('Valid from: ' + taf[index]['timestamp']['from']),
              Text('Valid to: ' + taf[index]['timestamp']['to'])
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, unfortunatelly error is the same, i have been trying:

```Text('Indicator: ' + taf[index]['change']['indicator']['text'] ?? 'No indicator')```


But error is the same :(

Comment: ```var changeIndicatorText = taf[index]['change']!=null?```, only this line will be enough, because during ```taf[index]['change']['indicator']!= null?``` you are trying to reach value that does not exist, only ```taf[index]['change'] == null```. Thanks for help in solving this problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
       ListView.builder(
              itemCount: taf.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
Text('Indicator: ' +
    taf[index]['change'] !=null &&
    taf[index]['change']['indicator'] !=null &&
    taf[index]['change']['indicator']['text'] != null?taf[index]['change']['indicator']['text']: "no")

    , // !!This element sometimes is present sometimes not!!
                          Text('Valid from: ' + taf[index]['timestamp']['from']),
                          Text('Valid to: ' + taf[index]['timestamp']['to'])
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, error is:

```The following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'```

PS. I also realised that the value of array that is not existing is not null